# How to validate the JSON Property value in Postman

Tags: postman

I wanted to validate the roleName in Test scripts. How can I do it if the JSON data has an array value?

This is my JSON object:

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "Operation completed successfully.",
"data": {
    "response": {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                page=0&size=20"
            }
        ],
        "content": [
            {
                "roleEntityId": 7,
                "roleName": "Content Creator",
                "description": "Content Creator",
                "roleId": "RID30392625",
                "createdDate": "2020-07-15",
                "links": []
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I tried  this

```
pm.test("Verify the Role name ", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.Content["roleName"]).to.eql("Content Creator");
   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test would need to be something like this, given the example response:

```
pm.test("Verify the Role name ", function () { 
    var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.response.content[0].roleName).to.eql("Content Creator")
})
```

The reference that you were making to the value was incorrect. The `jsonData` variable would give you all the response, you would having to drill down through the JSON to get to the `key`. `content` is also an array so you would need to add `[0]` to specify which object in the array you wanted.